# Nonclosable Operator: Example (Wikipedia)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

The example here is taken from the wikipedia article:
[Discontinuous Linear Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map#Closed_operators)

Given the spaces of polynomials $X:=\mathcal{P}([0,1])$ and $Y:=\mathcal{P}([2,3])$.

Their completions being $\hat{X}=\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ and $\hat{Y}=\mathcal{C}([2,3])$.

Consider the operator $T:X\to Y:p\mapsto p$.

Then its closure would be all of $\hat{X}\times\hat{Y}$. Nice!

But is this operator be well-defined:
$$p(x)=q(x),x\in[0,1]\implies p(y)=q(y),y\in[2,3]$$
*(I guess so as polynomials are analytic and therefore determined by any neighborhood of any point.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you knew $\deg p=d$ then $p$ is uniquely determined by its values at any $d+1$ distinct points. Even if we don't know $\deg p$, it follows that $p$ is uniquely determined by its values on a countable set of points (because that contains $d+1$ points no matter what $d$ is).